# adding actionBar to a fragment with DrawerLayout in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

going crazy with implementing aciton bar to my fragment,whatever I do I can not add a "title" or a menu to my toolbar (I used the code that is generated in android studio when creating new project with "Navigation Drawe Activity and put it in fragment- for referance)this is how my fragment looks like:

```
class BaseFragment : Fragment() {


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    var appCompatActivity = activity as AppCompatActivity;
    var view = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, true);
    var toolbar = view.findViewById<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.e_mail)
    appCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

    return inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, true)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)
}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
    inflater?.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
}

}
```

and my fragment_base:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

and the result  is:

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you set an action bar in the Fragment is a bad approach, because when the fragment is destroyed, that Action Bar will also be destroyed.

DrawerLayout on Action Bar is a sliding menu that appears on the android screen with a hamburger menu icon. You shouldn't destroy it on every fragment creation. You need to set Action Bar in your MainActivity.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(){

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

            // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
            val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById<Toolbar>(R.id.toolbar)
            toolbar.setTitle(R.string.e_mail)
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

            // Find our drawer view
            val mDrawer: DrawerLayout = findViewById<DrawerLayout>(R.id.drawer_layout);
        }
}
```

It will solve your Action Bar title issue. Hope it helps!